# PHP How can I fetch data from normalized tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have normalized tables I want to select the items that belong to the userid 
I'm familiar with select syntax but I'm very weak in joins tables so I'm a bit confused on how to get the items that belong to the user should I use join ?  or is there other way

this is just simple example of my tables they have more fields 
..........

user
..........
userid
firstname
address

..........

items
..........
itemsid
itemName
itemDescription

..........

user_items
..........
userid(FK)
itemsid(FK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two inner join

```
select a.*, b.* 
from user_items as c 
inner join user as a on a.userid = c.userid
inner join items as b on b.itemsid = c.itemsid;
```

Comment: may I ask what is c is it variable ?

Comment: `c` is alias for `select` query (TableName) .

Answer (score 0):

So if I read this correctly, user_items.userid = user.userid.

So you want to join, something like this.

```
SELECT i.itemsid, i.itemName, i.Description FROM items i JOIN users us ON ui.userid = us.userid JOIN user_items ui ON ui.itemsid = i.itemsid WHERE ui.userid = VALUE;
```

Replace Value with your actuall user id

Comment: scaisEdge beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN

**SQL**

```
select user.*, items.* 
from user_items 
  inner join user on user.userid = items.userid 
  inner join items on items.itemsid = user_items.itemsid;
```